# Trouble using input statement to look up results in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, text, line

I have my readme.txt file that I want to scrape data using Python.

The .txt file has games organized like this:

```
Green Bay Packers;Detroit Lions;42-21;2021

Kansas City Chiefs;Las Vegas Raiders;35-31;2021

Green Bay Packers;Houston Texans;35-20;2021

Chicago Bears;Jacksonville Jaguars;41-17;2021

Seattle Seahawks;Los Angeles Rams;20-9;2021
```

Data is written as `hometeam;awayteam;score;season`

I am Trying to write a code that so a user can input the teams name and I can calculate the output of:

- number of games team has played
- number of home games the team had
- number of away games the team had

I am just totally lost and don't know where to start or what to look up.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think you are over confusing yourself. This would be very hard to pull of even as a professional python developer. A more simple way of doing this if you want live data is making a online txt file with the number of games and displaying it with python

```py
from requests import get
URL = "https://example.com/example.txt" # the link for the text file
response = get(URL)
print(response.content)
```

Or you could retrieve data from a local file

```py
with open("example.txt") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

The Output would be something like

```
456 games
```

And combined with a input it would look something like

```py
def games():
    with open("example.txt") as f:
        print(f"they have {f.read()}")
ask = input("type a team ").lower()
if ask == "cougars":
    games()
```

I know this is tedious but it is the only solution I know of

Comment: For clarification the reason I didn't want to use it the way the question initially suggested it is because it is not possible to do that in a text document with python.